# Why does numpy integer subtraction produce a float64?

Tags: python, numpy, type-conversion

In numpy, why does subtraction of integers sometimes produce floating point numbers?

```
>>> x = np.int64(2) - np.uint64(1)
>>> x
1.0
>>> x.dtype
dtype('float64')
```

This seems to only occur when using multiple different integer types (e.g. signed and unsigned), and when no larger integer type is available.

Comment: The same behavior is not replicated when we subtract int32 with uint32 but the result is int64. Looks like numpy elevates to float as there is no larger integer type. I find any documentation regarding this conversion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a conscious design decision by the `numpy` authors. When deciding on the resulting type, only the types of the operands are considered, not their actual values. And for the operation you perform, there is a risk of having a result outside the valid range, e.g. if you subtract a very large `uint64` number, the result would not fit in an `int64`. The safe selection is thus to convert to `float64`, which certainly will fit the result (possibly with reduced precision, though).

Compare with an example of `x = np.int32(2) - np.uint32(1)`. This can always be safely represented as an `int64`, therefore that type is chosen. The same would be true for `x = np.int64(2) - np.uint32(1)`. This will also yield an `int64`.

The alternative would be to follow e.g. the *c* rules, which would cast everything to `uint64`. But that could, of course, lead to very strange results with over/underflows.

If you want to know ahead of time what type you will end up with, look into `np.result_type()`, `np.can_cast()`, and `np.promote_types()`. Reading about this in the docs might also help you understand the issue a bit better.

Comment: Aside from the documentation on those specific functions (which has fairly little to say about the broader issue), are you aware of parts of the documentation which *do* talk about this? I just searched for a while without finding anything.

Comment: No, it seems to be rather sparse. Some more information and explanation can be found, looking at the bug reports on the issue, e.g. https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/7126, which goes into some more detail.

Answer (score 3):

I'm no expert on numpy, however, I suspect that since `float64` is the smallest data type that can fit both the domain of `int64` and `uint64` that the subtraction converts both operands into a `float64` so that the operation always succeeds.

For example, in a with `int8` and `uint8`: `+128 - (256)` cannot fit in a `int8` since `-128` is not valid in `int8`, as it can only fit back to `-127`. Similarly, we can't use a `uint8` since we obviously need the sign in this case. Hence, we settle on a float/double as it can fit both directions fine.